# is the SMS sender the network provider or SMS provider?

Tags: android, networking, sms, sms-gateway

How to know is the message sender is my network provider let's say the sender name of my network provider is "Hoola" or someone how is pretending that he is "Hoola"

I hope my question is clear enough to be answered 
but to make it more simple

```
The sender hoola origin number is nothing or hoola - for network provider 
but for sms gateway provider is 101241212388 
Can I figure this when receiving SMS on Android ?
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What sms-gateway are you using? Or should I say what company services are you using?

Comment: There is a lot of SMS gateways and I can pretend that I am the network provider for example 

I can send SMS and the sender name is AT&T but its from gateway 
how to know its from a gateway not from company

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood it you need a SMS gateway with API-support and you also need a way to make sure that someone doesn't a represent himself/herself as a network provider to the end customer.

Well we've been having the same kind of trouble and I decided to switch to Infobip.

They filter out and warn you if someone is trying to misuse the service - like spam or misrepresentation(pretending to be someone else).
So you don't have to worry about users taking advantage of your app in order to send junk sms.

Ah...overall...I'm satisfied with [Infobip's](http://www.infobip.com) services and their support response time which is most of the time within minutes.

Rene.

Comment: I want to check the received SMS ?

Comment: That's up to the SMS gateway to check it for you. You yourself cannot be sure (as and end-user).All You can do is just rely on the company you hired to do the sms sending. It's their job to filter out fraudulent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Now a days, there are fixed Sender IDs allotted to users. So the Gateways allot the Users their preferred Sender IDs after proper authentication only. So there shouldn't be any such issue.

Comment: Your link to your site has nothing to do with answering the question that was posed.